# Hide space between elements of a report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, subreport

I have one report with various subreports. These subreports are within a table cell. When the subreport doesn't have any data available, I hide the components (tables, textbox, charts) in that subreport. However, this creates some blank space and I need to eliminate this space.

I already used the properties **ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace** and **KeepTogether**, but the blank space is still there.

Any suggestions to remove the blank space?

Comment: Does the subreport occupy the entire row in the parent report? If so, you can set the row visibility in the parent report to hide entirely when appropriate.

Comment: No. I have two collumns. One have the id, and the other have the subreport (the id was passed has parameter).
I cant verify the visibility in the row because data is in subreport.
Currently I am hiding components in subreport, but continues with the blank spaces. Therefore, the verification must be in the master report and no in the subreport.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. The cell in the parent report which contains the subreport will continue to exist. Do you want to hide the entire row or entire column? If not, then what should happen to that cell? (Also, make sure that your subreport's dataset returns no rows when you want it to be hidden. This will let you use the no rows message in the parent report. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220407.aspx )

Comment: I want to hide the entire row if the dataset that is not returning data in subreport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide or show an entire row based on another reports results will be difficult, if not impossible. You will need to get this data in your parent report somehow.

I would create a cut down version of your subreport's query that returns row count for every subreport, but within the parent report. Might look like this:

```
UserID   RecordCount
  Abby       3
  Bob        0
  Carl       1
```

If you are using SSRS 2008r2 you can then use a lookup function to set row visibility. For example the row visibility expression might be

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!UserID.Value,
       Fields!UserID.Value,
       Fields!RecordCount.Value,
       "LookupDatasetName") > 0,
    false,
    true)
```

If an earlier version of SSRS, then join that dataset into the dataset for your table.

Comment: I use SSRS 2008r2.
I tried to put the table inside a rectangle but continues with white spaces.

Comment: Can use the lookup function because the dataset in the subreport is a stored procedure with parameters. I cant count the rows for each user.

Comment: Understood. I propose creating a different dataset that gets the number of rows for each user. You can start with the existing SP's query and modify it slightly to return the row count for all possible users.

Comment: But, im creating the same dataset in the subreport, in the main report.