# Call dataset with stored procedure dynamically with single value parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I'll try to be clear enough with my situation.
I have one dataset `ds1` which has user IDs and have another dataset `ds2` (a stored procedure) which returns results for each id.

`ds2` (stored procedure) only accepts single value parameters, so I need to call for each ID instead of passing a multi-value parameter.

I have one table grouped by user, and in the second column I have the chart using `ds2`.
How can I pass the value of each user ID to `ds2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is to use a subreport: Create a report that has a single parameter and calls `ds2`. This report will be just the contents of one cell containing the chart.

Now place this report into the table you already created, as a subreport. Connect the user field value from `ds1` to the parameter of the subreport.

Another approach is to redesign your datasets, perhaps joining the to at the data provider.

Comment: The best solution is to use subreport. However, i'm in trouble with blank spaces as i shown in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647994/hide-space-between-elements-of-a-report

That's why I'm trying to put everything in the same report.